# Flink-Siddhi control event failing to start

Tags: flink-streaming, siddhi

While trying to configure and implement flink- siddhi(https://clojars.org/com.github.haoch/flink-siddhi_2.11/versions/0.2.2-SNAPSHOT)  control stream for rule ingestion , I am getting below error: Abstract method error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.lambda$generate$0(StreamGraphGenerator.java:305)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1361)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:449)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator.generate(StreamGraphGenerator.java:305)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2010)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getStreamGraph(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1995)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1834)
    at flinksidhi.app.s3.SiddhiTestApp.start(SiddhiTestApp.java:104)
    at flinksidhi.S3SidhiApp.main(S3SidhiApp.java:8)
```

Code for Control event:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", kafkaAddress);
properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect",zkAddress );
properties.setProperty("group.id","test_rule");
DataStream<? extends ControlEvent> ruleControlStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer("S3_RULE_STREAM_INPUT",
                new ControlEventSchema(), properties));
```

Any help on this will be much needed ...

Regards
Dipanjan

Comment: Just an update the above issue is not noted in case of Flink 1.11.0 , it is only happening in case of Flink 1.12.0 and 1.13.0

Comment: It could be the case that the Siddhi library only works with Flink <= 1.11.

Comment: True but is there any alternative for siddhi on fink in that case , or is flink planning anything on that or is Flink CEP is full fledged and can it replace siddhi in that case are few questions I have , to decide to use Flink CEP in that case.

Comment: The Flink community is not actively working on a replacement of the Siddhi library. You can check out whether FlinkCEP fulfills your requirements.